# How to rename package "AndroidTest" in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEdac.png)I got a ready resource and wanted to rename the AndroidTest folder just as I renamed the others, but every time I click on "refactor" and "rename" nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the following steps to do it:

- In your Project pane, click the little settings icon on the right & uncheck/De-select the `Compact Empty Middle Packages option` like this:

[image]

- Select the individual directories created from the package & select `refactor` by performing a right-click on it & rename. Choose `Rename All` when required like this:

[image]

- Open up app-level `build.gradle` and change the `applicationId` field inside `defaultConfig` with your new package name and sync like I changed it to `newone` below in my `build.gradle` file:

[image]

Hope this helps!